# Send a string with sendto() function in C

Tags: c

I have to get the numbers in a buffer with recvfrom() function and compute the sum. Then I have to use sprintf() function to get the result as a string and then I have to send this string with sendto() function. Everything is fine is my code except the result that I send with sendto(). Could you help me please ?

```
int recv_and_handle_message(const struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t addrlen)       {
// TODO: Create a IPv6 socket supporting datagrams
// TODO: Bind it to the source
// TODO: Receive a message through the socket
// TODO: Perform the computation
// TODO: Send back the result
int result = 0;
int sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(sock == -1) return sock;
int err = bind(sock,src_addr,addrlen);
if (err == - 1) return err;
struct sockaddr_storage recever;
socklen_t len = sizeof(recever);
char buffer[1024];
int rec = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(char)*1024, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&recever, &len);
if(rec == -1) return rec;
int*current = (int*)&buffer;
for (int i = 0; i < rec/4; ++i){
    result += current[i];
}
char res[1000];
int b = sprintf(res, "%d", result);
if(b == -1){
    return -1;
}
char rese[b];
memcpy(rese, res, b);
//for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i){
  //  rese[i] = res[i];
//}
int r = sendto(sock, &rese, 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recever, len);
if(r == -1){
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable. Add empty lines to split it up into paragraphs, and please uses indentation, *consistent* indentation.

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What is the actual behavior? What is the expected behavior? What is being sent, and what did you expect being sent? And what efforts of [*debugging*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) have you made?

Comment: And considering `int*current = (int*)&buffer;`, perhaps it's an *endianness* issue?

Comment: Or an *alignment* issue. `int` might need 32bit alignment whereas `char[]` does not.

Comment: `sendto(sock, &rese, 1,` You only send 1 byte while `b` is likely to be larger I would assume. BTW: You could just send directly from `res` buffer without copying it to yet another buffer first.

Comment: Please also edit the question to include the data you receive. (Together with the changes already requested above)

Comment: Note that `&rese` is wrong. It's a pointer to the *array*, not a pointer to the first element. Pass plain `rese` (which will decay to `&rese[0]`).

Comment: Ok thank you guys, I had to put res and b instead of &rese and 1 in the sendto() and I had to use htonl(result) when using sprintf.